# Can you publish a .war directly from eclipse to a web server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, publish

Can you publish a .war directly from eclipse to a web server.

I know it's not a programming question, but I still think it's a relevant question.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify I meant a remote web server i.e. through SSH or FTP

Answer (score 4):

yes you can.

right click on the project, select export -> select web - > then war and give destination which is your deploy folder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it depends a lot on your project configuration. Generally you need to define the server in eclipse, and choose "Run on Server".

See [this](http://www.laliluna.de/articles/webprojects-eclipse-jbosside-tutorial-en.html) as an example of deploying on JBoss server from eclipse.
In case you are using Ant then using "deploy" target will work.

Comment: You're misstaken at least about the maven part. The deploy stage in the maven lifecycle is about deploying an artifact to a maven repository and has little to do with deploying to a web server

Comment: @Buhb Thanks for pointing. We have the deploy target to deploy to local server. I mixed these two things :) Updating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty easy:

1. Import the war file into eclipse. File > Import... > Web > WAR File.
   (likely only works on eclipse for java ee development)
2. Pick the war file, create a new project (any new name works), click finish
3. Add the new project to your server
4. Blam!

Answer (score 1):

If your project is setup as a web project in Eclipse, you can choose to run it on a server (You'll have to configure the server first). This will publish the war file directly on the server from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest if the web server has an auto-deploy facility, with a magic directory.   Then just File-> Export the WAR file into the auto-deploy folder.

If not, or if you want to be able to debug the WAR file inside Eclipse you need to have an appropriate server connector in the WTP module (which is included by default in the Java EE edition of Eclipse).

If you want to programmatically push the WAR file to a given server directly from within Eclipse, then you can e.g. use the Tomcat Ant tasks - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing%20Manager%20Commands%20With%20Ant - or use the Cargo library to do this with many different types of servers - http://cargo.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0):

I created my own ant file, and set eclipse to use that ant file when building.
Part of that ant build file is a target that publishes to Tomcat, so I can just right click
and chose install from within eclipse.

[Eclipse pic http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/6701/eclipseant.png](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/6701/eclipseant.png)

The basis of such an ant file is here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/build.xml.txt

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you do that

- Start the build the application
- Create the war file 
  A WAR (or "web archive") file is simply a packaged webapp directory. It is created using the standard Java jar tool. For example:

cd /home/alex/webapps/mywebapp 
jar cf ../mywebapp.war * 
- copy that war file to the following deploy directory in your server
say in Jboss its like this
"**C:\Jboss405\server\default\deploy"**

I hope this might be clear, else let me know any issues if you face any issues