# What tools are recommended to use to publish codes to staging server

Tags: eclipse, deployment, ant, publish, staging

I do my web development in Eclipse (PDT) locally. Usually, I need to publish my changed codes onto staging server to preview. For last 5 years, I have been using ant script (build.xml - ftp task) to ftp the codes onto server. I am just wondering maybe there is a better tool to do the similar/better job. Can anyone share your experience?

Thanks,
xin

This is a sample ant script target:

```
<target name="deploy-live" description="FTP files from ${source} to staging server">
    <ftp server="${live-server}" port="${live-server-port}" userid="${live-userid}" password="${password}" depends="no" verbose="yes" passive="yes"
            remotedir=".">
        <fileset dir="${source}">
            <include name="abc/**"/>
            <exclude name="**/Thumbs.db" />
        </fileset>
    </ftp>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) might be an alternative. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760297/remote-deploy-tomcat-webapp-from-eclipse) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407151/can-you-publish-a-war-directly-from-eclipse-to-a-web-server) should help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out Maven.